# Creating a Windows Server 2003 image on Windows 7

Tags: virtualization

Is it possible to create a Windows Server 2003 image on Windows 7 and if so, what software would you use to achieve this?

Comment: Is your question, you want to run a VM of Server 2003 on Windows 7? Is this for testing purposes to be used by you or accessed by others. Some more details about what you are trying to do are needed.

Comment: I just want this for testing purposes, so it will only need to be accessed by me.

I want to test some admin scripts I am writing for IIS6 admin and I am not able to connect to a windows server 2003 box presently.

Comment: This is perfectly possible and there are a wide variety of virtualisation software choices that you can use for this. Install, for example, VMWare server and then install windows 2003 inside the VM. Job done.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any virtualization software you want that can run on Windows 7; the simplest (and free) choice would be Microsoft's Virtual PC, which you can download and install from here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc.

Just don't get tricked into downloading "Windows XP Mode", which is a XP VM with tight integration with the host system; it's quite a big download and totally useless if you don't need it; get only Virtual PC and use it for all your Windows Server 2003 virtualization needs.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 does come with Virtual PC built in. (Not 100% if this is version dependant IE not Home) but this would allow you to create a virtual image of a Windows Server 2003, which you could access.
If this sounds like something you would like let me know and I will expand my answer to include all of the details for you.